# Java ResultSet.updateRow() throws MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I spend 2 days already trying to figure this out, but still could not get what is wrong with the code. So whenever I'm trying to update Date in Resultset and  updating row after I  get this syntax exception. It's all seems like simple, but I'm just doing something wrong. Could you please help me with this pain.

```
public class TableTest extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fishman", "root", "");
        Statement stm = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customers where id = 3 or id = 189 or id = 310 or id = 12 order by Date ");


        while(rs.next()) {
            Date date = rs.getDate("lastcontact");
            if(date == null) {
                rs.updateDate("lastcontact", new java.sql.Date(new Date().getTime()));
                rs.updateRow(); // Throws exception here
            }
        }

        rs.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

and this is exception I get

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.UpdatableResultSet.updateRow(UpdatableResultSet.java:2411)
    at com.TableTest.main(TableTest.java:50)
```

Comment: Try adding `FOR UPDATE` to the end of your SELECT.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but still no change

Comment: You could try to log what gets sent to MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html.

Answer (score 1):

This might be it:

> "Using ResultSet.updateRow will set the PK of a table (in the
>   generated UPDATE statement) even if the PK field was not in the list
>   of fields to update. This causes problems when permissions do not
>   allow the user to update certain fields in a table (e.g. the PK)."

from https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71143

from further research, this basically looks like a MySQL bug that was found but never fixed...

One way around it can be to not fetch the PK into the resultSet in the first place
(for example, instead of
`"SELECT * FROM tbl"` where col1 is the PK, do
`"SELECT col2, col3..."` etc.)
That workaround has one obvious downside - you don't have the PK column in your resultSet to work with.

But in your case that might work - if "lastcontact" is not your PK (and it probably isn't), you can change

```
SELECT * FROM customers where...
```

to

```
SELECT lastcontact FROM customers where...
```

This just might work.

Hope this helped.